# How to make a batch file loop resume from where it was by looping through the files listed on a .txt?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I want to start down mixing hundreds of surround media files in a folder to stereo, but this is a process that will take a lot of time. I'd like to create a batch file that executes my `ffmpeg` command to this set of files (probably listed in a .txt with `dir /s /b`) that I can run whenever my PC is on, but also keeps a record of already processed files to be excluded on the next run.

I know I can easily keep track of already processed files by simply adding something like `if errorlevel 0 echo "%%~fg">>processed.txt` to my loop, but I'm finding it challenging to come up with a way to ignore these files when running the script the next time.

Of course I could always manually edit the file list to be looped and remove the ones already processed, but I wonder if there is a clever way to do it programatically

Comment: one option would be to maintain a log file of proccessed files, and use findstr to search the log and process conditionally based on whether the file being processed exists in the log.

Comment: Are you using `ffmpeg` to _create_ new files? If so, just test if the corresponding new file does not exist in order to create it. If you are creating files in an incremental way thru several passes, you may suspend/cancel the process of one file until you have crated a *complete file*.

Comment: @Aacini I'll actually be replacing files. `ffmpeg` will create a .tmp file, then the script will delete the old one and rename the new one to take it's place.

Comment: @T3RR0R that seems it could work, would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: I guess this also can be done by running two `for` loops one inside the other: the first one iterates through the file list from `dir` and then the second iterates through the whole log file comparing `%%G` to `%%H`. If a match is found, a variable is set and it this makes the post processing be skipped. I'll try to elaborate this into an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to produce a way that doesn't rely on external tools and executes the job only with `for` loops. As it was needed to use UTF-8, extra steps were taken to properly revert the codepage after the batch file ended:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') do for %%H in (%%G) do set /A "CodePage=%%H" 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1

if not exist "%~dpn0.log" break >"%~dpn0.log"

set "FileList=%~dp0FileList.txt"
set "LogFile=%~dpn0.log"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%FileList%") do (
    set "SkipFile="
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%H in ("%LogFile%") do (
        if "%%G" == "%%H" (
            set "SkipFile=1"
        )
    )
    if not defined SkipFile (
        echo --^> Processing file "%%~nG"
        rem file is processed
    ) else (
        echo "%%~nG" has already been processed
        rem file is not processed
    )
)

%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %CodePage% >nul

endlocal
```

As can be seen, part of this answer is inspired by @[T3RROR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12343998/t3rr0r)'s!

Answer (score 0):

An example of using a log with findstr. replace the definition of `Set "SourceList=%~dp0list.txt"` with the filepath of the file used to store the list of files for processing, or modify the for /f loop options to iterate over the output of your `Dir` command.

```bat
@Echo off

 If not exist "%TEMP%\%~n0.log" break >"%TEMP%\%~n0.log"

 Set "SourceList=%~dp0list.txt"
 For /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%sourceList%")Do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Findstr.exe /xlc:"%%G" "%TEMP%\%~n0.log" >nul && (
        Rem item already processed and appended to log. do nothing.
    ) || (
        Rem item does not exist in log. Proccess and append to log.
        Echo(Proccess %%G
        >>"%TEMP%\%~n0.log" Echo(%%G
    )
 )
```

Comment: So, it seems `findstr` has a limitation when dealing with accented characters, such as `à`, `á`, `è`, `é` and so on. Could this be achieved in another way?